# How to not trigger hover effect on element underneath another element without javascript

Tags: html, css

I have looked at some other posts and all I could find was answers using javascript. Is there some way that I hover over an element on top of another element but the element at the bottom won't change its style?  By the way, I only want to use vanilla HTML and CSS, no javascript.  In this example, the goal is to hover over blabla or blablabla without adding a border to the navigation bar.
**HTML**

```
    <div class="navBar">
        <div>
            <h1 id="Title">A Random Website</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="navBarChild">
                    <a href="blabla.html" id="linkBla">Notepad</a>
              
                    <a href="blablabla.html" id="linkBlaBla">Help</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navBar{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid gainsboro;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    
 }
 #Title{
    color: black;
    font-family: monospace;
 }
 .navBar:hover{
    border: 2px solid black;
 }
 h3{
   z-index: 2;
 }

body{
   background:url("...") left / cover no-repeat;
}
.navBarChild{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   position: relative;left: 290px;top: 17px;
}
#linkBla{
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 26px;
   font-family: monospace;
   color: black;
}
#linkBla:hover{
   color: orangered;
}
#linkBlaBla{
   position: relative;left: 50px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 26px;
   font-family: monospace;
   color: black;
}
#linkBlaBla:hover{
   color: orangered;
}
```

Comment: It's far from possible. But it would be great if somebody would find the solution of this problem.

Comment: To be clear, you want the black border on .navBar to appear on hover EXCEPT if Notepad or Help is hovered over? In which case the black bar should disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add a new 'navBarContainer'

Try bringing the 'navBarChild' out of the 'navBar' like this:

```
<div class="navBar">
  <div>
    <h1 id="Title">A Random Website</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navBarChild">
  <a href="blabla.html" id="linkBla">Notepad</a>
          
  <a href="blablabla.html" id="linkBlaBla">Help</a>
</div>
```

Make a whole new 'navBarContainer' for the both of them

```
<div class="navBarContainer">
  <div class="navBar">
    <div>
      <h1 id="Title">A Random Website</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBarChild">
    <a href="blabla.html" id="linkBla">Notepad</a>
          
    <a href="blablabla.html" id="linkBlaBla">Help</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set the '.navBarContainer' in your css to 'position: relative;'

```
position: relative;
```

Set the 'navBarChild' to

```
position: absolute;
display: flex; //to keep the a-links together
```

and then you can position it to your desire

```
top: 0; //important
left: 75%;
height: 100%;
```

At this point there should be no need for the z-index

### Lastly

Add a little padding to the #linkBla and #linkBlaBla and set the display to 'flexbox'

```
#linkBla, #linkBlaBla {
  padding: 40%;
  display: flexbox;
}
```

Checkout the whole thing in this pen https://codepen.io/emekaorji/pen/mdOMMRr

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible without javascript, but you can put the script inside of the HTML like so:

```
<html>
<body>
...
<script>
  function removeOutline() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navBar")[0].style.border = "2px solid transparent";
  }

  function addOutline() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("navBar")[0].style.border = "2px solid black";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and use it like:

```
<div class="navBarChild" onmouseover="removeOutline()" onmouseout="addOutline()">
```

CSS does not allow you to change elements above the current element. In other words, you can't change the parent element based on the child element (the reverse works by using child selectors).